# How to create stretching clipping rectangle in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, clipping

Since Silverlight doesn't have the comfy feature of 'ClipToBounds' properties on controls, I have to define clipping shapes by myself. I was wondering if I could create a clipping rectangle that's following the size of my control. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an existing control in you layout that you want to dynamically clip then use its `SizeChanged` event.  For example lets say you want to clip this Grid:-

```
    <Grid SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged" Width="50" Height="20">
        <Grid.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry />
        </Grid.Clip>
        <TextBlock Margin="0 -9 0 0" Text="This text should not be legible" />
    </Grid>
```

With the code-behind:-

```
   private void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((RectangleGeometry)((Grid)sender).Clip).Rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, e.NewSize.Width, e.NewSize.Height);
    }
```

For a your own custom control you might consider handling the clip rectangle in the `ArrangeOverride` instead of relying on the SizeChanged event.  In this case you probably want to assign RectangleGeometry to the `Clip` property in code rather than relying on it being assigned in the Xaml of the default template.

Comment: I made a Behavior for FrameworkElement which does what you've described. Now I have ClipToBounds in Silverlight! :) Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight supports that:
try using HorisontalAlignment and vertical alignment propertys. Set them to stretch.
If this doesn't work then you will have to post xaml example.

Comment: The alignment properties do not affect the clip region of a control.

Comment: Will ClipToBounds work if the parent have triangular form?I'm asking this code if your parent is always rectangular then alignment property's are that you are looking for.

Comment: You seem to be quite confused about what the WPF `ClipToBounds` actually does. Its function is about clipping not sizing or alignments.  The alignment properties are entirely irrelevant to the question.